# jquery and ASP.Net AJAX framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net. I am new to jQuery and ASP.Net AJAX framework. Suppose I need to use jQuery function (e.g. from jquery-1.3.2.js). I want to confirm that jQuery and ASP.Net AJAX framework are totally two different things, no dependencies?

So, no need to install and configure ASP.Net AJAX framework in order to use jQuery function?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct. You don't need both to function. You can find information on the AJAX toolkit [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/). You might also find [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) quite useful. I'm quite new to Jquery as well and found JqueryUI to be quite a time saver. If you want, you can also let Google host Jquery and/or JqueryUI for you, so your bandwidth doesn't get taken up ([Info here)](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery). Just to add, if you want intellisense with your Jquery code, [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) shows you how to setup VS2008 to do so.

Comment: Access denied for the 1st link?